# Sum of digits of a factorial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

[image]

This is question from my college math test for JEE . In this question we are asked to find the missing digits of 19!. I skipped this question in my test but I tried it after the test and I made many errors while calculating it. Is there any way i can find the missing digits within 2 minutes since we are expected to do 60 lengthy and hard (like the above one ) questions in 2 hours.

I would like to thank you for helping me to solve this problem .

Comment: My tired old eyes have difficulty picking out what might be available only in your image.  Essential details of the problem statement should be provided as text.  An introductory note on posting [math notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) may be useful.

Comment: @markvs No, it isn't 3.

Comment: @markvs Are you guessing? That's not how one do things in Mathematics.

Answer (score 5):

$19!$ is multiple of $1000$ so it has to finish with three $0$'s. So $H=0$.
Also $19!$ is multiple of $9$, and of $11$, using the criteria for divisibility by $9$ and by $11$ you can find some equations satisfied by $T$ and $M$.